# iOS Swift - Remove last method from stacktrace

Tags: ios, swift, crash, crashlytics, stack-trace

I have a utility method for logging various non-fatal errors in my project. In this method I also send the error to Crashlytics by its `record()` method, but when looking at Crashlytics, all errors are grouped together into one instance, beacause the last info in the stacktrace is line `x` of my `UtilityClass` (where `Crashlytics.crashlytics().record(error: error)` is called).

Can I remove from the stacktrace the reference about the last method before calling `Crashlytics.crashlytics().record(error: error)`? And how to do it?
There are other ways?

I'm looking for a way to tell Crashlytics that all my non-fatal events are not coming from the same line of code, but from the line that calls that line, so that all the events are not grouped togheter.

Comment: I am not experienced with Crashlytics, but from browsing the documentation is seems that record(exceptionModel:) does what you want.

Comment: @MartinR I've used `record(exceptionModel:)` instead of `record(error:)`, but I lose all the stacktrace info except the custom ones that I manually add. 
Maybe I can solve this by retrieving the current stacktrace, remove the last item, and add it to the custom `exceptionModel`. I didn't previously thought about that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the crashes will be grouped together based on the highlighted blamed frame and not necessarily by the top frame in the stack trace. This means that crashes with different stack traces could end up in the same issue if the same frame is blamed on both.

This is what I mean by blamed frame:
[image]

If the latest frame is related to your utility method and that is the one being framed, expanding on what you mentioned in the comment about using the [ExceptionModel](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=ios#customize-stack-traces), I came up with this workaround:

```swift
var exMod = ExceptionModel.init(name: NSURLErrorDomain, reason: "some reason")
var stack: [StackFrame] = [];

// The current stack trace is obtained after removing the first element
for frame in Thread.callStackSymbols.dropFirst(){

   // The frame is a String, the address value is obtained and appended to the stack array.
   let frameArray = frame.description.split(separator: " ");

   // The address is a String and is converted to a UInt value
   let address = UInt(frameArray[2].dropFirst(2), radix: 16) ?? 0
   stack.append(StackFrame(address: address));
}
// The stack trace is added to the ExceptionModel
exMod.stackTrace = stack;
Crashlytics.crashlytics().record(exceptionModel: exMod)
```

This is the result of running this snippet without “.dropFirst()”:

[image]

And this is the result dropping the first element:

[image]

As you can see, the first element was removed as expected.

My suggestion would be to first try causing different crashes on different parts of your app and see if the same frame is getting blamed. I.e: Checking if those crashes keep getting grouped.

Then check if the above snippet works for your use case.